# Redirect URLs from Wordpress with ?post= or ?cat= in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I need to redirect a mass of old Wordpress short urls that begin with question marks such as:

/?post=731

Or

/?cat=73

I need them to be instead /page

I tried

```
RewriteRule /?cat=73$ http://www.mydomain.com/page? [R=301,L]
```

Didn't work

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=73$
RewriteRule ^/$ page? [L,R=301]
```

Didn't work.

Each old URL will have to be manually redirected to a new url.  Meaning:

```
/?cat=73 goes to /category-73
/?cat=2 goes to /main-category 
/?post=731 goes to /this-page
```

These are just examples.
Each old link will have a NEW link - no one size fits all.

I have about 500 URLs like this.  Anyone got any good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=73$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category-73? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /main-category? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No that did nothing.  I may not have made myself super clear.  Each old URL will have to be manually redirected to a new url.  Meaning:
/?cat=73 goes to /category-73
/?cat=2 goes to /main-category 
/?post=731 goes to /this-page

These are just examples.
Each old link will have a NEW link - no one size fits all.

Comment: see update, it will have to me multiple rules OR else you can RewriteMap